# How to make a C program to find the interval of a root of an equation

Tags: c, root, intervals, equation-solving

I need help making a C program that calculate the root intervals of a given equation. I made a program based on the concept that if f(a)f(b) < 0, then there exists at least one root in (a, b).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define f(x) x*x + 2*x + 1

void RootInterval(){
    float a[10];
    float b[10];
    float begin, end;
    begin = -50;
    end = -50;
    int count, i = 0;
    while(begin < 50){
        if(f(begin) >= 0){
            while(f(end) >= 0){
                end = end + 1;
            }
            a[i] = begin;
            b[i] = end;
            begin = end + 1;
            i++;
        }
        else {
            while(f(end) < 0){
                end = end + 1;
            }
            a[i] = begin;
            b[i] = end;
            begin = end + 1;
            i++;
        }
    }
    count = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);
    printf("Root interval is:\n");
    for(i = 0; i < count; i++){
        printf("(%f, %f) ", a[i], b[i]);
    }
     
}

int main(){
    RootInterval();
    return 0;
    
}
```

But when I run the program, nothing appears on the screen. What am I doing wrong here?

I tried different intervals and different conditions. I was expecting all root intervals in the range of (-50, 50).

Comment: Did you forget parentheses in `main`? Should be `RootInterval();`, not `RootInterval;`. Enable compiler warnings (`-Wall -Wextra -Werror` command line options for gcc) to catch such stuff.

Comment: Based on the **assumption** (not "concept") that if `f(a)f(b)<0` then there is one root in (a,b). That assumption is true if f continuous, for example. Otherwise, you don't know that.

Comment: If b > a, f is continuous over [a,b], and f(a)f(b)<0 then there is at least one root in (a,b).

Comment: Aside: the parentheses should be *in the macro*: `#define f(x) ((x*x) + (2*x) + 1)`

Comment: @WeatherVane: `((x)*(x) + 2*(x) + 1)`.

Comment: For what purpose, ```math.h``` and ```string. h``` have been included in this code?

Comment: @ImanAbdollahzadeh I'm having an assignment to make a program with multiple functions using menu, this is only one of them, so the library are for the other functions

Comment: @yeputons I did that, but the there's still nothing on the screen, and the return value is a very large number, not zero. So there must be something wrong with the code.

Comment: @TiếnĐạtLê I guess since you increment your ```float``` values by ```1```, such as ```end = end + 1```  or ```begin = end + 1```, you miss your root value somewhere in between.